# spring batch multiple input joining

Tags: java, parallel-processing, spring-batch

we've got a "special" challenge here which we try to master.

We have several csv-files, which are connected via ids. Bit lets keep it simple and  talk about just 2 files:

```
persons.csv:

3, john, doe
1, janet, doe
2, chief, programmer

addresses.csv:

1, street1, city1
3, street2, city2
2, street3, city3
```

as you see we need to **combine the data from one csv file with another** to create a person containing an address -> and the data is **NOT SORTED**.

My first thought: create the readers, processors and writers (we're currently just joining the data -> we want to store it in a message log) for every file.

We have a lot of more files with a lot more data. So when we first read all data, and aftrer that start to join we get an **OutOfMemoryException** because of Java heap space.

Now the Question:

What would be the correct way for (maybe) joining the data while it is gathered from the files? Is there a possibility for that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advocate for one of two approaches:

1. Sort the files - A control break pattern is common in file processing.  If you want to only use the files for input sources, this is the best option.
2. Input the files into staging tables - Use a database to load the files into staging tables then using SQL to join.  This is probably the easier option if you don't have access to something like syncsort.

Comment: Yes, your second suggestion was allready our intention to "solve" it, but we had some hope there would be a better approach.